# Transferring text from one file to another - Python

Tags: python, file-io

I'm trying to write a program that reads a file called "all_years.txt" (full of years), line by line, and calculates whether a year is a leap year or not. If so, I want to write that year into a different file that's empty called "leap_years.txt".

This is code I have so far and I just can't figure this one out. It's driving me crazy honestly. I'm not very experienced with programming, so I'd appreciate the some with this one.

```
# calculation function
def leapYear(year):
    """ Calculates whether a year is or isn't a leap year. """
    return year % 4 == 0 and (year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0)

# main function
def main():
    try:
        file = open("all_years.txt", "r")
        lines = file.readlines()
        file.close()

        for line in lines:
            if leapYear(line):
                file2 = open("leap_years.txt", "w")
                file2.write(line)
                file2.close()
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you keep both files open and read your input file line by line. You would need to use a regular expression to try and extract a number from the line. In this case it extracts just the first number it finds, so you would need to think what to do if there was more than one on a line:

```
import re

def leapYear(year):
    """ Calculates whether a year is or isn't a leap year. """
    return year % 4 == 0 and (year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0)        

with open('all_years.txt') as f_input, open('leap_years.txt', 'w') as f_output:
    for line in f_input:
        year = re.search(r'\b(\d+)\b', line)

        if year and leapYear(int(year.group(1))):
            f_output.write(line)
```

So if `all_years.txt` contained:

```
2001 
2002 
2010 
1900 
1904 World's Fair 19ol 
1946 
1984 
2000 
Year 2004 is a leap year
```

You would get `leap_years.txt` containing:

```
1904 World's Fair 19ol 
1984 
2000 
Year 2004 is a leap year
```

Answer (score 0):

modify the following line

```
file2 = open("leap_years.txt", "w")
```

to

```
file2 = open("leap_years.txt", "a")
```

when you use "w", it will create a new file every time.

Comment: There is another error in leapYear function. It takes str as argument, so TypeError is raised

Answer (score 0):

```
# calculation function
def leapYear(year):
    """ Calculates whether a year is or isn't a leap year. """
    year = int(year)
    return year % 4 == 0 and (year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0)

# main function
def main():
    try:
        file = open("all_years.txt", "r")
        lines = file.readlines()
        file.close()

        file2 = open("leap_years.txt", "w")

        for line in lines:
            if line.isdigit():
                if leapYear(line):
                    file2.write(line)
        file2.close()
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)

main()
```

Comment: Open file only one time , and in the for loop only write the leap years and once you have traversed all the lines i.e. your for loop is ended , close the file. Another thing is in your leapYear() function , change year into int type

Comment: Ok thanks, but I should mention, there are also letters in the file. How would I get the program to ignore letters? It kind of looks like this:
2001
2002
2010
1900
1904 World's Fair
19ol
1946
1984
2000

Comment: Is this entire text on one line ?

Comment: No, sorry. it's one per line, but some of the lines, as you can see, have letters. And I'm trying to get it to only output the leap years, ignoring all words or letters thrown into the mix.

Comment: Check now , isdigit() will do the job

Comment: It's finally printing to the "leap_years.txt" file, but only prints the last line on the "all_years.txt" file, which is 6464. No clue why it's only the last line.